# How to show one window for one monitor for all desktops?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I have two monitors for Windows 10 and multiple virtual desktops. How can I configure Windows to keep windows with "Process explorer" on the second monitor regardless of the opened virtual monitor? E.g., I open "Process explorer" on the second monitor and change virtual desktop so that the first monitor changes screen but on the second there are still "Process explorer" windows. Or maybe move these windows automatically to selected virtual desktop for second monitor.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with the build-in virtual desktop solution Microsoft provided. Keep in mind, this is a relative new feature that was introduced in Windows 10 and it lacks a lot of features other virtual desktop software offers.

If you seek this functionality, you will have to look for a different Virutal Desktop software package.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature in [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/).

- Settings > Taskbar > Taskbar Mode
- From: "Windows Taskbar shows all windows, DF shows relevant windows".
- To: "All Taskbars Show Relevant Windows"

Tested and works.

[Source](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/__/?ID=a94fef06-df36-4aa8-8361-0925efa20e8f) ([on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190707070837/https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/__/?ID=a94fef06-df36-4aa8-8361-0925efa20e8f))